# Configure xfreerdp to always pass some options

Tags: configuration, xfreerdp

I need to configure xfreerdp to be set as 15 bpp every time is launched, without the need of use the

```
# xfreerdp --sec rdp -a 15 --no-bmp-cache srvaddr
```

Opening the `config.txt` of `xfreerdp`, shows me the IP of the server, and if I add `/bpp:15` or `-a 15`, the program won't launch.

What is the correct syntax for this config file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sad to say there is no such option as storing settings in a config file with xfreerdp.

What you could do instead is use a scripting language and wrap xfreerdp by adding this functionality support.

For new cli versions of xfreerdp:

```
xfreerdp /bpp:15 ...
```

For deprecated cli versions:

```
xfreerdp -a 15 ...
```

Comment: Ow... sad to ear that, thank you my friend

Comment: If I change system depth, will it change the rdp conecction bpp?

Comment: It should as the default value is the depth of the root window. Keep also in mind that the color depth may also be limited by the server configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I like to use a combination of aliases and functions in `.bashrc`:

```
export RDP_OPTS="/d:... /u:... /bpp:32 +compression +fonts +aero +home-drive +clipboard"

rdp() {
    xfreerdp $RDP_OPTS /h:1050 /w:1680 /v:$1
}

rdp1() {
    xfreerdp $RDP_OPTS /f /v:$1
}

rdp2() {
    xfreerdp $RDP_OPTS /f /multimon /v:$1
}
```

This gives me three handy commands which take a server name as their only parameter:

- `rdp` - rdp session in a window
- `rdp1` - full-screen rdp session (1 monitor)
- `rdp2` - full-screen rdp session (2 monitors)